# Calculating New Velocity Vector of Moving Object

Tags: forces, momentum, velocity, inertia

A 1kg object is moving through space. A force is applied to the object of 1N perpendicular to the direction of travel for 1 second.

Assuming there are no other external forces on this object, (gravity, friction, etc.) what method would I use to determine which direction and how fast the object is moving after this force is applied?

EDIT:
After a short break from the computer, I had an epiphany on the solution to the problem. Prior to this, I was missing a key element - an acceleration vector.

After adding an acceleration vector:

$\vec a=F_{net}\div m$ where $\vec a$ is a 3 dimensional acceleration vector.

then

$\Delta\vec v=\vec a\times t$ where $\Delta\vec v$ is a 3 dimensional velocity delta vector, $a$ is the above acceleration vector and $t$ is time.

Comment: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is what method should be used, the answer is Newton's second law. I've explained the process below so if you're trying to solve it yourself you can skip reading that.

The object would accelerate in the direction perpendicular to its current motion. Specifically, since $F=ma$, $F=1 \, N$ and $m=1\, kg$ you must have that $a=1 \frac{m}{s^2}$. So since the force is applied for 1 second the object accelerates at one meter per second per second for 1 second, therefore its final velocity in the direction of the force will be 1 m/s.

Comment: I sincerely do appreciate your good intentions in your answer, and the careful way you worded it, but could you resist looking at the full answer, I couldn't : ), this will be **yet another** Google listed answered homework question. and the OP, despite your genuine effort to help, will have learned less than he might have.